# How to trigger a popup message on click the close button of a jqueryui window?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui

I want to trigger message on click on the close button of a jqueryui window.

See the jqueryui window here. All I want is to give a confirmation message on click the close button.

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach an event listener on the [beforeClose](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-beforeClose) event:

```
$("#dialog").on("dialogbeforeclose", function(event, ui) {
    // do stuff, presumably return false to prevent closing the dialog
});
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. can you please give me a complete example with beforeClose event?

Comment: There's nothing much to add, actually. A [simple example](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#entry-examples) is provided by jQueryUI's doc pages. All you have to do is to either attach the event listener just like above, or pass it with the `beforeClose` option. Notice that the event `dialogbeforeclose` can bubble, so you can add the listener on any of the dialog's ancestors.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this code:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
   beforeclose: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

Comment: `beforeClose` should be in camel case when passed as an option

Comment: it is taken from here http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.8.4/docs/dialog.html . It seems ok